British skit - couple at awful restaurant, but his "favourite" because they give WAY too much change!
Short feature before the main film at the theatre, or maybe a skit in a Brit TV series, maybe 1980's? I'm thinking Michael Pailin or John Cleese? He's taking his date (wife?) to a restaurant he's discovered, raves to her about how wonderful it is. Turns out to be a total farce of incompetence throughout the meal, she's shocked and disgusted, he smugly keeps telling her "just you wait".
At the end he pays the bill, and the owner gives him his "change", keeps counting out dozens of hundred-pound notes or whatever, Cleese knowingly grinning at his astonished wife the whole time, they gloat on their way out the door, vowing to return again soon.

Was it black & white?  From the style of humour it sounds like "It's a Square World" from the 1960s.

Nope, I think as I said I may have actually seen it in a cinema in the 80's. Possibly 70's clothing styles though def not 60's.

You're after The Absent-Minded Waiter, a 1977 short film with Steve Martin, Teri Garr and Buck Henry which was shown before Martin's stand-up performances (and in the beginning of Homage to Steve) and was nominated for an Oscar. From Wikipedia:

A couple (Henry and Garr) have gone out to dinner at a fancy restaurant the husband claims has the world's most absent-minded waiter. Martin plays a poor waiter. [...] The film culminates with the wife becoming angry that she got dressed up, hired a babysitter and then was brought out to a restaurant with such amazingly bad service. The husband pleads with her: "Trust me . . . trust me." Immediately afterwards, the waiter returns with their "change" – $10,000 worth – before the couple had even paid.

Here it is in its entirety [the sound improves after a minute]:




Oh thank you so much, you don't know how grateful I am. Can't believe got my wires crossed all the way across the Atlantic, I'm a big Steve Martin fan too!

Possibly a long shot, but could it be from an episode of either Monty Python's Flying Circus (entirely sketch comedy, had both Palin and Cleese) or Fawlty Towers (created by and starring Cleese, and that sounds like exactly the kind of thing that Cleese's character would do)? Neither of them came out in the '80s, but Fawlty Towers at least was in the mid- to late '70s, so pretty close. (The Monty Python group also made some movies in the '70s and '80s that may have contained similar scene(s), such as Meaning of Life.)

There's no scene like this in Fawlty Towers.

There's no scene like this in the Monty Python movies. I'd like to point out it could also be from the British TV series "The Two Ronnies". Sounds like their kind of humor as well.

Possibly sketch from a TV show, so Flying Circus is possible, but I've Googled the heck out of all relevant terms and nothing, which is why I'm thinking a movie short, I think maybe from when I lived in Oz. . .
Pretty sure it's John Cleese, for some reason I see the actress as JC's wife from Wanda, but that's very likely crossed wires in my poor brain, I was doing a lot of drugs back then, and now I'm old. . .

Is there a place that summarizes all the MP series' episodes?

Also posted here: https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/3csso1/tomt_movie_monty_python_restaurant_great_because/
